# Why is Big O not defined here for a hash table?

Tags: computer-science

In this cheat sheet, average time complexity for access to a hash table is listed as N/A.

I'm curious as to why.  Since a hash table is mostly mathematical with out looping, I would assume it would be O(1) like the other operations ... Search, Insertion, Delete.

http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: Link to cheat sheet is missing.

Comment: You should try here : https://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

In that table, the 'access' column refers to time to access a given element, by index. That is why in an array, access is described as O(1) - returning the ith element of an array is a constant time operation. Similarly, for a linked list, it is an O(n) operation - if you have a linked list, and want the item at index i, you need to jump from link to link, i times.

Now, in a hash table (dictionary, hashmap etc), we do not talk of the 'element at index i' - we do not talk of indexes at all! That is what this table means by having NA as the value for 'access' for hash tables. We simply do not do (in the sense used here) 'access' operations on hashmaps.

Perhaps an explicit example might help.

`myLinkedList = ['red','blue','orange']`

`myArray = ['black','white','green','yellow']`

`myHashMap = {'address':'10 wall st', 'gender':'male'}'`

In the first two examples, we can *access* the element at a given index.

Ie:

`myLinkedList[1] == 'blue'` and `myArray[0] == 'black'`

But we cannot *access* hashmaps by index.

`myHashMap[0]` is not defined in this instance! So 'access' is NA to hashmaps.

However, we have the equivalent, in this context, operation: search by key.

Ie:

`myHashMap['address'] == '10 wall st'`

An O(1) operation.

Whether you asked the question because you do not know data structure internals (in which case, do learn them, it is worth it), or if you were merely confused by the terminology on that cheatsheet, I hope this answer helped.

Comment: Do we typically access a stack or queue item by index?  I would think not, but it does have a Big O for access.  Though I do see how these could be considered linear as well.